# Best way to handle self signed certificates

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, self-signed

I recently ran into an issue where I'm trying to fetch a resource from a site. The site has been associated with self-signed certificate. When I request resource through WebRequest, it throws the following error:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

I did look out for solutions. I don't want to disable checking for certificates altogether. In short, I wasn't able to find a convincing answer. Please let me know the best way to deal with self-signed certificates.

Comment: That error means that the underlying TCP client wasn't able to validate the authenticity of the server. There are different ways of doing this that involve certificate provisioning. For example, loading the self-signed certificate into you Personal store to use Peer Trust validation.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: In a typical scenario, with TLS enabled, the server presents a certificate to the client during a handshake process before establishing a secure connection. The certificate allows the client to cryptographically validate that the server is authentic (to prevent spoofing) before the client would accept the connection and send potentially sensitive information to the server. This server validation in your client can be skipped (not recommended) at your discretion.

Comment: Is there any way to make it accept self signed certificates? I prefer not to skip validation.

Comment: You can install the server certificate into your Personal store. Try searching for examples of accessing the Windows Certificate Store and how to configure Peer Trust validation. You shouldn't need to write any more code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Trusted People store.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is important to know, that this exception is preventing you from accessing possible fake web server by checking site certification trust.


Self signed certificates can be trusted, but you have to **install** it's root CA into system **trusted CA store**.


It you insist on trusting server that is signed by self signed certificate without installing it's root ca into trusted CA store, you can force the check mechanism to trust anything with this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Or better approach to set this forced trust only to HttpWebRequest instance:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Comment: I'm using ASP .NET 4.0. I don't think I can do this. 
   request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };